# ILR set o form(question on previous countries visa refusal)

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

My wife is on ILR (Indefinite leave to remain) (through tier 2 General)I am qualified to apply for my ilr (Tier 2 dependent) since 21/02/2019 but am having issues with filling and answering a question on set o form.

My case: I consulted a visa consultant to apply for USA Business visa around 2001 and 2002.Along the line I had a disagreement with him when he was asking for more money. So he didn't brief me the outcome of the visa application. I tried to get more information from him but he didn't give any. My concern is that I don't know if he applied or any reason for the refusal.

In 2010 I applied for my Tier 2 dependent and there was a question if I have been refused any U.K. or any other countries. I ticked yes but only mentioned my refused U.K. visitor visa and the Tier 2 visa dependent was successful. All through my extensions is here in the U.K. I have not met such question again. 
I applied for USA tourist 2016 which was refused due to no enough family ties. On the USA visa application it was asked if I have applied for USA visa before which I ticked yes. 
Now to my set o form, a question was asked about previous visa application (refusals) I have mentioned all my U.K. and the 2016 USA visa refusal. My question is how do I declare the one I gave to the consultant between 2001 and 2002? Because I don't want to trigger deception on my ILR application. I do not have any information about the visa application. I stand to be corrected, I believe it will be safer to bring it to their notice so as to avoid ILR refusal through deception. 
I just want to play safe .Please kindly advice me on what to do.

Comment: Our community recommend to move this question to Expatriates and I think that is the right thing to do. They are about long term stays and have more knowledge on the visa for that. (And I am a mod, in case you do not recognize the icon with my name.)

Comment: @Speedboy80, Just explain the situation with that visa as you have explained it here: That you were working through an agent, you don't know if the application was ever made or what its outcome was. That should suffice in case something actually happened with that and it shows up on their queries.